# Maintaining hyperlinks/references when tagging in Subversion

Tags: svn, hyperlink, reference, ms-office

I am managing a project for which we use Subversion as our version control system. According to company quality processes we must store all project related data in the repository including MS word/excel/power point documents.

Whenever we pass our final milestone and release a product/version we create a tag in SVN to baseline the current state of things. The challenge is that during project execution we use SVN hyperlink references between documents and folder (e.g., linking to a business case excel file from within a power point presentation or linking to a word document from within an excel sheet). These SVN hyperlinks are absolute by default and points to trunk, which means we loose the link to the **baselined** version of that linked document whenever we create the project tag.

Is there a way of creating *relative* references in the MS office tools or somehow using a special form of hyperlink that is somehow still valid after tagging? Or is the only way forward to update all occurrences of "trunk" to "tags" prior to tagging?

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html

Comment: Could you give an example of the links you have?